# alert in stackdriver for not receiving msg after 24 hours in google cloud

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I want to monitor that a pod in kubernetes is running correctly as cronjob twice a day using stackdriver.

In order to do it I want to send start msg and end msg logs in the pod and I want to create an alert metric in stack driver that if not receiving these msgs after 24 hours, send Email.

Is it possible to do this alerting in stack driver ?

Comment: What about if the job you want to schedule logs a message that it has completed.  You could then capture that message in a stackdriver log.  Now you could create a stackdriver log filter that matches that specific message.  Now you could create a metric that counts the number of times that message appears in the log.  Finally you could have an alert that fires if the message is not seen at least once every 24 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways of accomplishing this.

In order to generate the event, I think the easiest way is to check on a log-based metric based on the CRON itself. If you are running a `kind:CronJob`, you can either use the Metrics Explorer to find Resource `type:GKE Container`  `Metric: Log entries`, and then filter by `container_name` (which will be your CronJob `spec.containers.name`)

You could also create a log based metric on something like

`logName="projects/[PROJECT-ID]/logs/[CONTAINER-NAME]"`

...and maybe add a string to the `spec.containers.args` section to make filtering easier.

You could also publish to a pub/sub topic and do your alerting on publish message operations.

Once you decide on the metric, you just need to alert if `Any time series is absent`[1] for 13 hours. Add a notification channel `type=email`[2], and you will receive an alert whenever the cron does not run at least once a day.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#condition-types

[2] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#email